# POST from jquery 1.8 $.ajax returned 304. wrong apache configuration?

Tags: php, apache, jquery, httpd.conf, http-status-code-304

I shoot the following Post request to a remote apache server,hosting a small php script:

The POST:

```
var request = $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'http://my.server.on.port/mmm.php',
    data: { abc: "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" } })
    .done(function(data) { alert("success :"+data.slice(0, 100)); });

request.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
    alert( "Request failed: " + request.reponseText + " " + request.status  +" " + request.statusText +" " +request.responseText  );
});
```

mmm.php script:

```
<?php echo json_encode(array("first"=>"XXXXX","last"=>"YYYYY")); ?>
```

httpd.conf:

```
ServerName my.server.on.port
DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"

<Directory "/var/www/html">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>

NameVirtualHost "my.server.on.port"
Listen 80

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/QR/tst"
    ServerName "my.server.on.port:80"

    <Directory "/var/www/html/QR/tst">
            Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
    </Directory>

    <Directory "/var/www/html/QR/tst/css/smoothness">
            Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
    </Directory>
    <Directory "/var/www/html/QR/tst/development-bundle">
            Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
    </Directory>
    <Directory "/var/www/html/QR/tst/development-bundle/ui">
            Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
    </Directory>
    <Directory "/var/www/html/QR/tst/development-bundle/demos">
            Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

The reply from the server is 304. all files has 755 permission. No idia how to solve this. thanx!

```
HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified
Date: Sat, 21 Jul 2012 08:45:38 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.22 (Fedora)
Connection: close
ETag: "c0744-f7a-4c553071e0d4e"
```

this is the alert with the error:
[image: alert]

Comment: To solve what? What's wrong with 304?

Comment: I cant get the response from the php(which is simple ,and should return first=xxx&last=yyyy   .. why can't i get 200? whats wrong with the configuration?\

Comment: 304 means "its not modified" you are sending the same result

Comment: Okay, so why the ajax .fail callback is called uppon 304? instead of .done

Comment: btw after clearing cache its the same :\

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This Works for me (tested on chrome and IE):

```
 var request = $.ajax({
     type: "post",
     url: "mmm.php",
     data:"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz",
     success:function(data){ alert("success: " +JSON.stringify(data)); },
     error:function(data){ alert("error "+JSON.stringify(data)); },
     statusCode:{
          200:function(){alert("200 OK");},
          304:function(){alert("304 Not Modified");},
          404:function(){alert("404 No Found");}},
     isModified:function(){alert("Something was modified");}
 });
```

Thanks to anyone that helped!

Answer (score 1):

try this ajax request

```
var request = $.ajax({
type:"post",
url:"http://my.server.on.port/mmm.php",
data:"abc=abcd",
//success:function(data){ console.log("success "+data); },
//error:function(data){console.error("error "+data;},
statusCode:{
200:function(){console.log("got 200")},
304:function(){console.log("got 304")},
404:function(){console.error("got 404")}},
isModified:function(){console.log("Something was modified");}
}).responseText;
// i haven't used .done .fail but i believe the code below would work.
request.done(function(data){ console.log("got response "+data); }); 
request.fail(function(jqXHR,textStatus){ 
console.log("Request Failed\n"+"object dump :"+console.log(jqXHR)+"\n"+"textStatus :"+textStatus); 
}); // changed according to the example from jquery site.
```

Comment: Deprecation Notice: The jqXHR.success(), jqXHR.error(), and jqXHR.complete() callbacks will be deprecated in jQuery 1.8. To prepare your code for their eventual removal, use jqXHR.done(), jqXHR.fail(), and jqXHR.always() instead.    all this from http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/   , I'm using jquery 1.8 so this applies to me.

Comment: redited haven't used 1.8 a lot but i think the request would work.

Comment: it does work, though i can't parse the error i'm getting! its [Object Object] .. any idia?

Comment: edited again, added more things at .fail you should get a understandable output, other than that use tools to debug with Firebug you can see everything from header sent to response ( which i assume you used to get the headers), also with firebug console you can write jquery (if library is loaded in webpage) and craft requests there.